# Oracle: Should we rebuild the indexes for a materialized view that was refreshed in non atomic mode?

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

We have a materialized view in Oracle 12c database, it is currently being refreshed completely and in non atomic mode [atomic_refresh => FALSE and complete refresh]. Also, there is a next step which explicitly rebuild all the indexes of the Mview which takes considerable amount of time in Mview refresh. Is this a correct approach to rebuild all the indexes once the Mview is refreshed in complete mode and in non atomic mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can tolerate that the MV is for some time empty you use the non-atomic refresh, which basically makes a `TRUNCATE` and (direct) `INSERT APPEND`.

You have two choices with the indexes, either you drop them before the refresh and re-creates them when the refresh is finished or you let Oracle Oracle do the job (with a very similar effect). The truncate resets the indexes to the empty state and the last step of the `INSERT APPEND` build them new from the scratch.

I’d prefer to use the second option.

A separate step of *rebuilding indexes* (which may be required on heavy updated tables with long duration transactions) is on a MV with non-atomic  full refresh not required.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, could you please help me to understand more on this " A separate step of rebuilding indexes (which may be required on heavy updated tables with long duration transactions) is on a MV with non-atomic full refresh not required." Does it mean that index rebuilding is not necessary for the Mview that was not-atomically full refreshed and needed only for the heavy updated tables?

Comment: Also, please confirm if explicit index rebuilding is required in case of complete, atomic refresh of an Mview.

Comment: Index rebuild is helpfull in (rather exceptional) cases, where the index size increases with a time and gets much larger that expected. I'm saying *this is not the case when you performs a non-atomic refresh of a MV*. You may simple verify it by observing the index metatdata in `select INDEX_NAME, BLEVEL, LEAF_BLOCKS  from all_indexes`. If the values after teh rebuild remains nearly the same, the rebuild had no significant effect. @D789rul